# Java Photoshop Script Execution

Tags: java

I am trying to execute `photoshop script` using `java` for that i use **following code**

```
  public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
        p.command("Photoshop.exe", "TestHelloWorl.jsx");
        p.start();
    }
}
```

But on different system photoshop exe file path is differnt .
Then how solve this problem.

Comment: Let the user input the path to Photoshop.exe if it cannot be found?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but that's not good.